# how to join below to queries in single query

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have following query,

How can I join these two queries into one.

```
SELECT BATCH_NUMBER   AS "BATCH NUMBER",
  ORD_NO              AS "ORDER NUMBER",
  ORD_ITEM_NO         AS "ORDER ITEM NUMBER",
  COUNT(BATCH_NUMBER) AS "BATCH COUNT",
  SUM(IP_WT)          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
 -- SUM(I.IP_WT) as "TOTAL WEIGHT" 
  CASE ORD_TYPE
    WHEN 'DOM-EXP'
    THEN 'Export to Chaina'
    WHEN 'DOM-SCS'
    THEN 'Export to USA'
    WHEN 'DOM-OEM'
    THEN 'Export to Oman'
    WHEN 'DOM-RET'
    THEN 'Export to Russia'
    WHEN 'EXPORT'
    THEN 'Export to Shri Lanka'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END AS "ORDER TYPE" ,
  CASE PACK_TYPE
    WHEN 'EXP-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Export'
    WHEN 'DOM-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Domestic'
    ELSE 'NA'
  END AS "PACKING TYPE"
FROM HR.BAF1_PDI
GROUP BY ORD_NO, ORD_ITEM_NO,BATCH_NUMBER, ORD_TYPE, PACK_TYPE
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

and

```
select SUM(I.IP_WT) as "TOTAL WEIGHT" FROM HR.BAF1_PDI I GROUP BY I.ORD_NO;
```

Comment: Please add `DDL`, some example data and expected result.

Comment: want two different column for  sum(ip_wt) group by batch_number and sum(ip_wt) group by ord_no

Answer (score 4):

Since you have different `GROUPING SETS`, you can use this clause:

```
SELECT BATCH_NUMBER   AS "BATCH NUMBER",
  ORD_NO              AS "ORDER NUMBER",
  ORD_ITEM_NO         AS "ORDER ITEM NUMBER",
  COUNT(BATCH_NUMBER) AS "BATCH COUNT",   
  SUM(IP_WT)          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
  SUM(I.IP_WT) as "TOTAL WEIGHT" 
  CASE ORD_TYPE
    WHEN 'DOM-EXP'
    THEN 'Export to Chaina'
    WHEN 'DOM-SCS'
    THEN 'Export to USA'
    WHEN 'DOM-OEM'
    THEN 'Export to Oman'
    WHEN 'DOM-RET'
    THEN 'Export to Russia'
    WHEN 'EXPORT'
    THEN 'Export to Shri Lanka'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END AS "ORDER TYPE" ,
  CASE PACK_TYPE
    WHEN 'EXP-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Export'
    WHEN 'DOM-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Domestic'
    ELSE 'NA'
  END AS "PACKING TYPE"
FROM HR.BAF1_PDI
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (ORD_NO, ORD_ITEM_NO,BATCH_NUMBER, ORD_TYPE, PACK_TYPE),
    (I.ORD_NO)
)
```

From there you can filter out any unwanted rows. A more manual version is to create union compatible results from two union legs:

```
SELECT BATCH_NUMBER   AS "BATCH NUMBER",
  ORD_NO              AS "ORDER NUMBER",
  ORD_ITEM_NO         AS "ORDER ITEM NUMBER",
  COUNT(BATCH_NUMBER) AS "BATCH COUNT",   
  SUM(IP_WT)          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
  NULL as "TOTAL WEIGHT" 
  CASE ORD_TYPE
    WHEN 'DOM-EXP'
    THEN 'Export to Chaina'
    WHEN 'DOM-SCS'
    THEN 'Export to USA'
    WHEN 'DOM-OEM'
    THEN 'Export to Oman'
    WHEN 'DOM-RET'
    THEN 'Export to Russia'
    WHEN 'EXPORT'
    THEN 'Export to Shri Lanka'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END AS "ORDER TYPE" ,
  CASE PACK_TYPE
    WHEN 'EXP-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Export'
    WHEN 'DOM-STD'
    THEN 'Standard Domestic'
    ELSE 'NA'
  END AS "PACKING TYPE"
FROM HR.BAF1_PDI
GROUP BY ORD_NO, ORD_ITEM_NO,BATCH_NUMBER, ORD_TYPE, PACK_TYPE

UNION ALL

select NULL   AS "BATCH NUMBER",
  ORD_NO              AS "ORDER NUMBER",
  NULL         AS "ORDER ITEM NUMBER",
  NULL AS "BATCH COUNT",   
  NULL          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
  SUM(I.IP_WT) as "TOTAL WEIGHT",
  NULL AS "PACKING TYPE"
FROM HR.BAF1_PDI I GROUP BY I.ORD_NO;
```

A third alternaive is to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT BATCH_NUMBER   AS "BATCH NUMBER",
  ORD_NO              AS "ORDER NUMBER",
  ORD_ITEM_NO         AS "ORDER ITEM NUMBER",
  COUNT(BATCH_NUMBER) AS "BATCH COUNT",   
  SUM(IP_WT)          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
  ( SELECT SUM(IP_WT) 
    FROM HR.BAF1_PDI 
    WHERE ORD_NO = I.ORD_NO ) as "TOTAL WEIGHT"
  FROM ...
```

A 4:th alternative is to join in the second query

```
SUM(IP_WT)          AS "ORDER WEIGHT",
...
X.TOTAL WEIGHT, 
...
FROM HR.BAF1_PDI
JOIN (
    select ORD_NO, SUM(IP_WT) as "TOTAL WEIGHT" 
    FROM HR.BAF1_PDI 
    GROUP BY ORD_NO
) X
    ON I.ORD_NO = X.ORD_NO
...
```

Comment: +1 for **multiple** solutions! I'll be studying this later on! :-)

Answer (score 0):

uncomment SUM(IP_Wt)  then
Add  `with cube  having ORD_ITEM_NO is null and BATCH_NUMBER is null` in the first statement before the order by 
add or delete in having the columns you don't need 'GROUP_BY_COLUMN is NULL  or NOT NULL'